# Is there standard Functionality to send an email to case owner when case is closed

Tags: workflow, standard-objects, email-alert

I want to send an email to the case owner after closing the case.

Is this standard functionality of Salesforce?

I tried in my developer org and I closed the case but I didn't get any email Notification.

Comment: I guess you can use Set Up Auto-Response Rules.. check this https://help.salesforce.com/apex/htviewhelpdoc?id=creating_auto-response_rules.htm&language=en_US#CreatingResponseRuleEntries

Comment: or you need to use workflow with email alert

Comment: ajay. is this issue resolved ?

Comment: @Ratan-Yes there is no standard functionality to send an email on case close. We need to set either auto response/workflow or other approaches..  Issue solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is any standard way to send email to case owner but for workaround go with workflow

You need to create workflow rule  where the records that enter the workflow is case status = closed.

send an email and you can select the case owner as the recipient.